# Substitute not-number value with Pandas not working for all

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to read values from a csv with Pandas. I have float columns like this in `test.csv`

```
a;b;c
1.4;2.4;-
2.3;4.9;3.8
3.1;5.3;2.7
6.6;-;-
9.6;n/a;3.8
2.3;3.4;6.3
1.4;6.5;-
3.8;-;2.0
```

I want the not-numbers to be `0.0`. I try

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    'test.csv',
    sep=';',
    encoding='utf-8'
)

df = df.replace(['-','NaN'], '0')
df.astype('float64')
```

but one value remains `NaN`

```
     a    b    c
0  1.4  2.4    0
1  2.3  4.9  3.8
2  3.1  5.3  2.7
3  6.6    0    0
4  9.6  NaN  3.8
5  2.3  3.4  6.3
6  1.4  6.5    0
7  3.8    0  2.0
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Remove the replace call and instead add the following argument to `read_csv`: `na_values=['-', 'n/a']`

Comment: @cs95 That alone will not do it, he also wants to replace the `NaN`s with zero values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a simpler way. You can add `-` as additional `NaN` value when calling `read_csv`. Then replace all `NaN` values using `fillna()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8', na_values=['-'])
df = df.fillna(0.0)
```

This gets you what you want directly with the correct `dtypes`.

---

FYI: If you wanted to fix your code, you would have to change your `replace` statement:

```
df = df.replace(['-', np.nan], '0.0')
```

Comment: You missed the fact that he has two types of NaN, '-' and 'n/a'. You have to add both to `na_values`

Comment: Actually, you dont. 'n/a' is already part of the standard values that get replaced by `NaN`.